# Elasticsearch sorting based on multiple aggeration

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, multiple-columns

I try to get my data with different aggeration criterias afterwards I want to order it based on one of aggeration criteria. In this specific case I want to get my data to be ordered descendly based on "Monthly_Income/ SUM" criteria.

I searched and tried lots of thing but none of them worked for me. Could you give me the answer because I am new on elasticsearch.

what I searched so far and couldn't solve the problem ;
"ordering_by_a_sub_aggregation,
Sorting Based on "Deep" Metrics,
search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-script,
search-aggregations-bucket-multi-terms-aggregation

To visualize the problem. I always get the belowing result however I tried lots of methods but  I couldn't achieve to get desired result.

**undesired result**
[image]

**desired result**

[image: desired result]

**Request**

`

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [],
            "must_not": []
        }
    },
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
        "GENDER": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "GENDER.keyword",
                "size": 10000000,
                "missing": "N/A"
           // ,"order": {"MARTIAL_STATUS>Monthly_Income_0.max" : "desc" }  
            },
            "aggs": {
                "MARTIAL_STATUS": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "MARTIAL_STATUS.keyword",
                        "size": 10000000,
                        "missing": "N/A"      
                     //   ,"order": {"Monthly_Income_0.value" : "desc" }                 
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "Monthly_Income_0": {
                            "sum": {
                                "field": "Monthly_Income"
                            }
                        },
                        "Monthly_Income_1": {
                            "value_count": {
                                "field": "Monthly_Income"
                            }
                        },
                        "SALE_PRICE_2": {
                            "sum": {
                                "field": "SALE_PRICE"
                            }
                        }
                    // ,"sort_by_percentage": {
                    //     "bucket_sort": {
                    //         "sort": [ { "Monthly_Income_0.value": { "order": "desc"   }         }     ]
                    //     }
                    //     }
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`

**Response**

`

```
{
    "took": 0,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 1,
        "successful": 1,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 10000,
            "relation": "gte"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "GENDER": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "Male",
                    "doc_count": 40959,
                    "MARTIAL_STATUS": {
                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                        "buckets": [
                            {
                                "key": "Married",
                                "doc_count": 35559,
                                "SALE_PRICE_2": {
                                    "value": 2.530239767013672E9
                                },
                                "Monthly_Income_0": {
                                    "value": 3.59618565E8
                                },
                                "Monthly_Income_1": {
                                    "value": 35559
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "Single",
                                "doc_count": 5399,
                                "SALE_PRICE_2": {
                                    "value": 3.7742297754296875E8
                                },
                                "Monthly_Income_0": {
                                    "value": 5.3465554E7
                                },
                                "Monthly_Income_1": {
                                    "value": 5399
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "N/A",
                                "doc_count": 1,
                                "SALE_PRICE_2": {
                                    "value": 87344.203125
                                },
                                "Monthly_Income_0": {
                                    "value": 40000.0
                                },
                                "Monthly_Income_1": {
                                    "value": 1
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "key": "Female",
                    "doc_count": 7777,
                    "MARTIAL_STATUS": {
                        "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                        "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                        "buckets": [
                            {
                                "key": "Married",
                                "doc_count": 5299,
                                "SALE_PRICE_2": {
                                    "value": 3.9976638293359375E8
                                },
                                "Monthly_Income_0": {
                                    "value": 4.4994796E7
                                },
                                "Monthly_Income_1": {
                                    "value": 5299
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "Single",
                                "doc_count": 2477,
                                "SALE_PRICE_2": {
                                    "value": 1.8698677312695312E8
                                },
                                "Monthly_Income_0": {
                                    "value": 1.8793502E7
                                },
                                "Monthly_Income_1": {
                                    "value": 2477
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "key": "N/A",
                                "doc_count": 1,
                                "SALE_PRICE_2": {
                                    "value": 101006.8203125
                                },
                                "Monthly_Income_0": {
                                    "value": 10000.0
                                },
                                "Monthly_Income_1": {
                                    "value": 1
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

`

I try to order based on an aggerate column but I couldn't able to achieve

Comment: can you add a sample json document

Comment: Hi Jaspreet, Thank you for considering of my problem. I didn't get your question. Do you want to see raw data on elasticsearch or you want to see mapping or without any criteria search result ?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your issue is that you want to group by on combination of gender and marital status

I have used [runtime mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/runtime-search-request.html) to concatenate fields "gender" and marital status and used term aggregation to group by on run time field and sorted groups based on sum.

```
{
  "size": 0, 
  "runtime_mappings": {
    "gender-maritalstatus": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "script": {
        "source": """
                 def gender='NA';
                 def maritalstatus='NA';
                 
                 if(doc['Gender.keyword'].size()!=0)
                      gender= doc['Gender.keyword'].value;
                 if(doc['Marital_Status.keyword'].size()!=0)
                      maritalstatus= doc['Marital_Status.keyword'].value;
                      
                 emit(gender+'-'+maritalstatus);
                """
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "gender-marital-grouping": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "gender-maritalstatus",
        "order": {
          "monthly_income": "desc"
        }, 
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "monthly_income": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "Monthly_Income"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Result**

```
"buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "Female-Single",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "monthly_income" : {
            "value" : 300.0
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "Male-Married",
          "doc_count" : 2,
          "monthly_income" : {
            "value" : 200.0
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "Female-NA",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "monthly_income" : {
            "value" : 100.0
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "Male-NA",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "monthly_income" : {
            "value" : 100.0
          }
        },
        {
          "key" : "Male-Single",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "monthly_income" : {
            "value" : 100.0
          }
        }
      ]
```